# why the graphic interface of some applications is overriding?

Tags: upgrade, gtk

after upgrading to ubuntu 17.04 the graphic of some application is overriding for example this is the graphic of calculator : 
[image]

Comment: Have you changed your theme, icon theme, or fonts?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and it was solved by `rm  ~/.xinputrc`

[Graphical glitch in background of windows after update to 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931994/graphical-glitch-in-background-of-windows-after-update-to-17-04/932022?noredirect=1#comment1476441_932022)