# Graphical glitch in background of windows after update to 17.04

Tags: unity, gnome, graphics, 17.04, amd-graphics

- I did update from 16.10 to 17.04.
- I am using latest radeon driver from ubuntu repository with reference AMD R9 290
- No errors in dmesg, /var/log/Xorg.* and applications do not write any error messages in terminal.
- Glitch appears always but only in some applications or it's parts for example in [bugged gedit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUvve.png) (app is working but instead white background there is a copy of what was behind window, right side was created by resizing).
- I tried to install amdgpu 17.10, 16.40 driver -> did not work, I was not even able to login
- I tried to use gdm3 instead lightdm -> not affecting bug
- I also tied to install gnome-shell and run gnome with metacity/compiz -> not affecting bug
- I tried to run gnome on wayland but everything was scaled ~10x and cursor was not visible so I was not able to actually see anything.

Does anyone met this bug?
Or does anyone know where to look for errors or what to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a fix for the `gedit` problem, and maybe it'll also fix your other glitches.

Remove the `.xinputrc` in your home directory. Log out and then log back in and retest `gedit`. Then retest your other things.

In the `terminal`:

```
rm -i ~/.xinputrc # to delete this file with a confirmation prompt
```

Comment: It did work, but I do not why. In my .xinputrc I had only run_im xim.
What was the problem with it?

Comment: @nic30 I don't know what's wrong with it. It'll recreate itself. All I know is that it took HOURS to find that problem. Did it fix any of your other glitches?

Comment: I do not see any other glitches.